# Как добавить свою переменную в файл настроек django проекта и вывести её значение в шаблон?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Есть ли вообще такая возможность, создать переменную например

```
TEST = "Test"
```

записать её в settings.py,
а потом как нибудь вывести в html шаблоне?

Comment: Как часто Вам нужно будет использовать значение? В плане количества шаблонов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если разово - то к контекст `view` пихаете

```
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.conf import settings
    context = {'SOME_SETTING', settings.SOME_SETTING}
    return render(...., context=context)
```

Если везде, во всех шаблонах, на всех страницах, то пишите `middleware` (будет доступна в `request`, собстенно туда и нужно будет запихнуть) [(дока)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/)

или `context proccessor` - только для шаблонов [(дока 2)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext). Его нужно будет подключить в `settings.py` в соответствующей настройке

```
from django.template import RequestContext

request_context = RequestContext(request)
request_context.push({"my_name": "Adrian"})
```

Вам скорее всего нужен первый или последний варинт